# Creating a List in EL

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Suppose I have a custom tag that takes a List of Strings:

```
<%@ attribute name="thelist" type="java.util.List&lt;java.lang.String&gt;"
    required="true" %>
```

How can I create this attribute in the jsp that calls the tag? I could use a scriptlet

```
<tags:list thelist='<%= java.util.Arrays.asList("blah","blah2") %>' />
```

but is there any way to do this using Expression Language, since that seems to be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EL 3 you can simply do `#{['blah','blah2']}` to create a list.

Answer (score 8):

If all you want to do is create the list, then you can use `[<jsp:useBean>][1]` to create the object in the desired scope:

```
<jsp:useBean id="thelist" scope="request" class="java.util.ArrayList" />
```

This works because ArrayList has a no-args constructor. However, the list won't have anything in it. And, as far as I know, neither EL nor JSTL provide a built-in mechanism for adding items to a collection -- they're both focused on read-only access. I suppose that you could define an [EL function mapping](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77078) to enable the `add()` method.

However, I think that you're better off not trying to force JSP to do something that it doesn't want to do. In this case, that means that rather than use a JSP tagfile, you should write an actual tag handler in Java.

Comment: is this still true 4 years later: "neither EL nor JSTL provide a built-in mechanism for adding items to a collection". Couldn't find a way to do this

Comment: @cahen - I haven't used EL heavily for several years, but I see no reason for it to change. JSP is intended as a view technology, and mutation is something that a controller should do.

Answer (score 3):

As [kdgregory says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421131/creating-a-list-in-el/1421392#1421392), you could do this with [custom tag library functions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio), though it won't be pretty. For example, something like this:

```
#{foo:add(foo:add(foo:add(foo:newList(), 'One'), 'Two'), 'Three')}
```

You are merely running into the limitations of what used to be called the [Simplest Possible Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/reference/techart/unifiedEL.html#Expression_Language_Beginnings_).

It would be easier to do this via some other mechanism, like a bean.

Comment: EL has new features since 2009: see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667650/pass-a-list-to-a-jsf-component-without-using-a-bean).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid scriptlet or ugly EL functions, you could use you own builder and fool the EL interpreter:

```
...

<jsp:useBean id="listBuilder" class="com.example.ELListBuilder"/>

<ul>
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${listBuilder['red']['yellow']['green'].build}">
      <li>${item}</li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>

...
```

Check the example here: https://gist.github.com/4581179